# CefSharp.WinForms 81.3.100 sample application crashes

Tags: c#, winforms, cefsharp

What version of the product are you using?
Nuget CefSharp.WinForms 81.3.100
What architecture x86 or x64?
x64
On what operating system?
Win10
What is the .net framework?
4.5.2
Are you using WinForms, WPF or OffScreen?
WinForms

What is the expected output? What do you see instead?
Winforms not responding/crash and no errors are seen in the debug.log file. Even sometimes machine not responding and need to do a hard reboot. Sometimes CPU/Memory utilization shoots up to 100%.
Please provide any additional information below.
I followed below steps for sample application test -

https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/173/how-to-use-cefsharp-chromium-embedded-framework-csharp-in-a-winforms-application
Below is the sample code to reproduce the issue:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form  
{  
public ChromiumWebBrowser chromeBrowser;  
public Form1()  
{  
InitializeComponent();  
InitializeChromium();  
}  
public void InitializeChromium()  
{  
CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();  
// Initialize cef with the provided settings  
Cef.Initialize(settings);  
// Create a browser component  
chromeBrowser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("http://google.com");  
// Add it to the form and fill it to the form window.  
this.Controls.Add(chromeBrowser);  
chromeBrowser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;  
}  
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)  
{  
Cef.Shutdown();  
}  
}
```

Comment: Already asked at https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/3150 please don't cross post. Just ask once.

Comment: ok no worries.. will track only https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/3150